# Interface conflicts java

Tags: java, interface, crud

I am currently working on a big project that includes three different types of CRUD. My ICrud interface includes the `<t>` to put in the desired datatype when I implement it.

My problem is that when I implement it in my third class, I wish to make one of the methods (readAll) use another datatype than the 4 other methods (CRUD). Is this possible in any way?

Right now I have the readAll method return the matching data type but returning null because it isn't used, and instead created another method readall2() that does return the correct datatype but isn't part of my interface.

The ICrud interface:

```
public interface ICrud<T>  {

List<T> readAll();

List<T> read(int cvr);

void create(T t);

void delete(int cvr);

void update(T t, int id);
}
```

how i implement it:

```
@Service
public class AdminRepository implements Ilogin<Admin>, ICrud<Driver>, 
IAdmin<Company>
```

how i wish to use the readAll:

```
public List<Company> readAll()
```

(not Driver, but driver for all other methods in the interface)

And I wanna add; at first, i had the readAll in iAdmin because it takes Company, but I have this readall method in 6 other classes that implements ICrud aswell.

Thanks for any help. :)

Comment: please provide a sample of your interface definitions to better clarify your description.

Comment: Indeed, it's extremely unclear what the problem is without a concrete example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a design problem, i recommend you read about SOLID principles in the following link:

https://scotch.io/bar-talk/s-o-l-i-d-the-first-five-principles-of-object-oriented-design

In a correct design, you should not at all implement an interface if you will not implement one of its methods (the readAll i your case). this means you are mixing concerns, and your interface must be split into smaller interfaces. perhaps splitting the readall into a separate interface will solve your problem. for example, instead of ICrud, create an interface for write operations alone, and one for read operations, and one for readAll.

there is many ways to solve your problem preserving the interface ICrud as is, such as using object as a retrun type, or generics or dynamics. but what solves your problem from its roots is following a good design as i mentioned above.

Comment: Yes that makes sense, we are still learning about design patterns in school and it sounds like a good idea to apply one here. Say i wanted to skip cut corners, would it be possible in the class where i implement, to simple say ICrud<Object> and then further down in the method specify?

Comment: No, i did not see your addition of the code when i answered, but still my advice still apply. your use of generics is better than using object. But still my advice is to separate the readAll into another interface such as IReadAll<T> this way you can have two interfaces IWriteCruds<T> and IReadAll<T>, when you implement those you can substitute IWriteCruds<Driver> and IReadAll<Company>.

Comment: That is a good point, i will do that. In the future, this will result in so many interfaces, how do you keep track of them? Sort them in folders?

Comment: In modern software development, we tend to follow functional principles, it is a good idea for each interface to have only one method or two. its is much easier to manage folders and files than to have messy code with fat big interfaces and implementations. it may sound weird at first, but once you followed that you will never go back again.